# connect raspberry pi to fax machine

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, gpio, linux, usb-audio

I want to connect raspberry to fax machine , because I want cypher message before transmit via landline phone .
how can do it , how can interface between rasp and fax machine ?

Comment: Baffled - a fax is a picture so how would you decode it at the other end?  Scanning and then convert the resultant image to data or get them to type it in?  A fax modem will let you control it directly but I think under Linux these are postscript devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [ATA box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_telephone_adapter) that convert the fax (Analog telephony) to SIP (aka VoIP, Voice Over IP). From there on, is another topic.

Comment: can you more explanation? can you send me schema explain what you say?

Comment: An ATA box has one connector for the FAX and one connector for LAN. And that make the ATA box accessible from the network via TCP/IP.

Comment: Have you read the link to the "ATA box" in the answer?

Comment: can tell me ATA name(Type) for used in my project?

Comment: Search for "ata voip" on ebay, just make sure they are **SIP** compatible

Comment: thank you very much .can i call you or chat for more information?

Comment: Discord, check my info

Comment: ATA connect between Rasp And Fax. in side connect Fax with ATA via Rj11 cable , and in another side connect ATA with rasp via Ethernet cable , but how connect rasp with landline to use PSTN as Voip

Comment: Mats Karlsson .can you help me please?

Comment: Mats Karlsson , can we chat in discord?

Comment: hi Mats Karlsson , please can i chat on Discord? i am studying you info and reach to good idea

Comment: Mats Karlsson , there is a mistake that happened  by posting the same question ?inadvertent error .thanks' any way

Comment: hello Mats Karlsson, are you angry from me?tell me please

Comment: No I'm not, is there a reason for it?

Comment: Mats Karlsson .can i chat with you on Discord . i want to show you some of my research .

Comment: now> i thing to use RS232 modem and USB modem with rasp and use simple exchange for connect between rasp and fax